# How are Animated Objects created?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, crafting

How might Animated Objects are created? These are the named monsters in the Monster Manual rather than the items in the spell *Animate Object*?

Golems are called out as needing to be created via a Manual of Golems, but I can't find anything specific for those Animated Objects. Also as there is no value/rarity I struggle to apply the *Creating Magic Item* rules in the DMG.

The accepted answer of suggested question: [What are the rules for making constructs other than golems?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56008/) seems lacking for this case.

I am looking for ways to apply the current rules, this has been done by an NPC but should the players decide to read up on the research he has done i'd like to give reasonably accurate figures.

Comment: Why are you looking for these rules? Do you want to use them as a player, to have them as a DM for an NPC, to create options for your players, or for some other reason?

Comment: @THiebert I have edited the question, but it's to get an idea as DM should the PC's replicate a NPC wizards activities

Comment: I get that the answers there aren't satisfying, but isn't this the same question as that one?

Comment: @Miniman When the answer states _I asked myself why would someone with access to 5th level spells try to get a CR 1 animated armor when he could get a CR 9 clay golem._ yet the creatures do exist and it also doesn't actually answer the question I have asked I see that it is similar, hence I linked it, but not an answer

Comment: @Whinja The answers are irrelevant here. Whether a question is a duplicate or not is determined solely by the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, if these are duplicates then I think this one is a much clearer question.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are making an apples and oranges comparison. D&D 5e clearly embeds the idea that PCs are PCs and NPCs are monsters and *they do not follow the same rules*. For example, it is *impossible* to create the NPCs in the back of the monster manual using the rules for PCs. Historically, this is in keeping with all editions of D&D except 3.X.

As such, it is perfectly acceptable for a DM to rule that the NPC can create animated creatures due to the custom Animated Creatures ability that *PCs don't not have access to*.

That said, what the rules say is (MM p.19):

> Animated objects are crafted with potent magic to follow the commands of their creators.

You are the DM, you decide what "potent magic" means. For me, a *Wish* spell springs to mind.

You might also want to look the *Figurines of Wondrous Power* (DMG p.169) which are uncommon to very rare magical items and provide similar benefits to animated objects (sort of) for an idea on how powerful such tings might be.

Comment: What Wizard in their right mind would risk a 33% chance to never cast the Wish spell again just for a floating sword that can be "killed"? Just speaking RAW here.

Comment: @Slagmoth None. But 1 wish might give you 1000.